# Could not connect to Twilio: open failed

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

In a Node.js project I use Twilio for video connections, sometimes I am getting the error message when I trigger the call. It says in the log `Could not connect to Twilio: open failed`, also I monitored the network in logs, it says can not be opened and it's still not connected. Anyone had this issue? What was the solution?

```
 // Join the Room with the token from the server and the
          // LocalParticipant's Tracks.
          Video.connect(resdata.token, connectOptions).then(roomJoined, function (error) {
              log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incident is reported for group rooms, you can wait until it is fixed. Check the status: https://status.twilio.com/incidents/2t0jh1jkxp39